# iPhone - MPMoviePlayerController - Window not showing when playing audio

Tags: iphone, media-player, audio-streaming

I'm trying to play Audio URL (streaming URL) in MPMoviePlayerController.
(I'm aware of AVAudioFramework to play). I want to show the view with controls where user can pause, play, change volume etc with MPMoviePlayerController. That's why I'm using MPMoviePlayerController.
The audio is playing, but I'm not seeing the media player. Why?
I'm using the following code:

```
-(void)playMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL attachTo:(UIView*)parentView autoPlay:(BOOL)autoplay showControls:(BOOL)showcontrols repeat:(BOOL)autorepeat autoExit:(BOOL)exit
{
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = showcontrols ? MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded : MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = autorepeat;    
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = autoplay;
    [moviePlayer play];
    [parentView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When playing audio with MPMoviePlayerController, it won't show any view. Only with video, it will show a view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the frame of the movie player view:

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = parentView.bounds; // for example
```

If you prefer a fullscreen display, use:

```
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

(and remove the `[parentView addSubview:moviePlayer.view]`)

Comment: I added that as you said. Now it shows a narrow bar in the middle of the screen with play button, timer, progress indicator, and time duration of the audio. But it didn't show full screen view.

Comment: This didn't work. Its not showing the view at all now. Also its not showing done button (even if only controls are being shown) to close the audio player and return back to app.